# How to remove user input from a text input box with Jquery on submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't seem to get this to work for the life of me. I've tried setting the value to `''` with `getElementById('guess').value` and `$('#guess').val`, tried using `$('#formGuess').reset()`, etc. Don't know why the value won't clear out.

Here is my code on this:

js

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var guess = $('#guess').val();
  $('#guess').removeAttr('value');
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
          <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="guessForm">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Guess" id="guess"/>
              </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" value="Guess" id="submit"/>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: `$('#guess').val("")`

Comment: he said he tried that

Comment: `document.getElementById('guess').value` will just get the value of the input, to overwrite it you can use `document.getElementById('guess').value='';` or jQuery `$('#guess').val('');` If you find those still do not work please check your browser console for error reports.

Comment: My advice would be to monitor when the form is submitted, rather than when the submit button is pressed. Once the form is submitted and you have collected the data you need, you can reset the form, not one element. `$('#guessForm').on('submit'...`

Answer (score 4):

Set empty string as the value of textbox like following.

```
$('#guess').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code,

```
var guess = $('#guess').val();
```

you are getting the value not setting.

To set the value

```
$('#guess').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should attach a "submit" listener to the form, not to the button, e.g.

```
<form id="someForm"></form>

$("#someForm").submit(function () {
    // your code
});
```

But if you want to attach it to the button, then you can do that, no worries.

Make sure that the event is called. Are you sure that the function within "click" event is called? Put there a console.log("someText");

If it's called, then make sure that jQuery is getting the right element. Maybe you've made a typo? Maybe there's a missing "#" sign? Or maybe the jQuery is not loaded at all?

Open developers tools and check what's in the console.

Probably you've made a simple mistake - it's always about simple mistakes. : )